# MySQL workbench - Can't connect to a specific database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm facing a strange issue here and it seems impossible to me to connect to my `MySQL` database.

I have used the workbench few times ago, but it was an older version. The problem with the new one (6CE) is that I can't connect directly to a database - it only allows me to create a connection to the server as a root user and I don't remember this password.

Is there a way to make a connection directly to the dataase itself as in the previous versions, or now only the root is an option. If yes I will have to reset my password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your credentials are still valid, and has proper privileges. If you can log into your mysql-server from terminal (with root account or the user you are trying with), then run "SHOW GRANTS" and see the privileges;

To connect to mysql database you need to have your user account's hostname specific to your IP or wildcard (%).

Similarly you can create a new mysql user with the following command from your server, and then try with this new user.

```
GRANT ALL ON <db>.* TO 'user'@'<ip or %>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>' ;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Be careful with the user created above. It will have ALL privilege with the specific database. And using % is actually a bad idea, so user you home machines IP (from where you are trying to connect with Workbench)